# Trouble with fortran( ) to generate FORTRAN code from MATLAB symbolic expression

Tags: matlab, fortran

I did a number of symbolic manipulations and obtain an expression for my variable z. I used the following code to generate the FORTRAN code for z:

```
fortran(z,'file','FTRN_2Mkt_dfpa1');
```

The program stops after about 10 min, and I get these error messages:

```
??? Error using ==> mupadmex

Error in MuPAD command: Recursive definition [See ?MAXDEPTH]; during evaluation of 'generate::CFformatting'

Error in ==> sym.sym>sym.generateCode at 2169 tk = mupadmex(['generate::' lang], expr, 0);

Error in ==> sym.fortran at 43 generateCode(sym(t),'fortran',opts);
```

I think the problem is that the z expression is too long. The MuPAD software is treating this long expression as an infinite recursive operation. I am guessing that the MAXDEPTH in the fortran() source file is set at a level that is smaller than needed to convert the z expression to FORTRAN. If my guess is correct, is there a way to change MAXDEPTH in the fortran() source code?

If my guess is wrong, what can I do to generate the FORTRAN code for the z expression?

I really need the FORTRAN code for the symbolic expression of z. If you can help me, it would be wonderful. Thanks a million in advance!

Best, Limin

Comment: How does your expression look like?

Comment: We can't help without seeing what `z` is. It may not have anything to do with length, per se – the error indicates that the expression (or some underlying function) is recursive in some way. I assume [`sym/ccode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ccode.html) produces the same error? You should also indicate which `version` of Matlab you're using.

Comment: The MATLAB version I am using is R2011a. For the expression of z, it is very long, longer than 25,000 characters. I manage to save z's expression in a .m file. I can upload it here if you want. Let me know. Thanks.